# .desktop shortcut fails to launch program

Tags: wine, launcher

I have .desktop file on my desktop that serves as a launcher for my application. Recently, i changed the command line for that launch and now clicking on the shortcut gives no visible effect.

Here are contents of .desktop file:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name=World of Tanks
>
> Exec=sudo -u windows -H env WINEPREFIX="/home/windows/.wine-wot" wine C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\WotLauncher.exe
>
> Type=Application
>
> StartupNotify=true
>
> Icon=7680_WoTLauncher.0

Command in `Exec` entry works fine when launched from terminal. Sudo is configured so that no password is required (only for those 2 commands for that user).

What could be the reason for failure to launch via shortcut? How can i try and fix or diagnose this situation?

Comment: try quoting the path `"C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\WotLauncher.exe"`, or wrapping the command in `bash -c "COMMAND GOES 'ERE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting the path - e.g:

```
"C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\WotLauncher.exe"
```

you can also try wrapping the command in:

> bash -c "*COMMAND GOES 'ERE*"